# Tmux special character support

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to remap the movement keys (between panes) in tmux to a Vim like style.

I don't like 'hjkl', and therefore I prefer to use the 'jkl;' keys. On my keyboard, the ';' character is 'ç' instead. I'm doing this:

```
bind j select-pane -L
bind k select-pane -D
bind l select-pane -U
bind ç select-pane -R
```

But it seems that tmux doesn't recognizes the 'ç' key. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, *tmux* does not really support binding keys whose core characters have multibyte representations. The internal key representation is mostly “8-bit plus modifiers”. Most terminals use UTF-8 these days, so your c-with-cedilla (U+00E7) is probably two bytes: C3 A7.

It should work if your terminal is using an 8-bit encoding. You would need to make sure your terminal is configured correctly, and also that your *tmux* client does not use UTF-8 (do not use the `-u` option, make sure LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, and LANG all do not include `UTF-8` or `UTF8`), do not enable the `utf8` window option, and make sure your configuration file is saved with the same encoding that your terminal uses.

---

When parsing key strings from (e.g.) the `bind-key` argument, *tmux* treats any multibyte sequence (after stripping leading modifiers) as a named key (e.g. `Up`, `PageUp`, `F1`, `KP0`, etc.); see `key_string_lookup_string` in `key-string.c`. This is what causes the `unknown key` error message.

I have also previously written about this at Super User: [tmux: trying to bind utf8 key](https://superuser.com/a/518203/14827).

Comment: Good explanation, it works fine now thanks to your Super User comment. Thank you very much for the help.